# Arduino Leonardo(Atmega32u4) - Detecting if USB is connected to a computer?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, atmega32u4

The closest thing I can find is if(Serial) but that only returns true if there's a serial port open.

The function I want, ideally, should:

Return true if plugged into a computer

Return false if plugged into a USB power bank

Return false if not plugged in at all(Running off of its own lithium cell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ADDEN` of `UDADDR` is set if the '32U4 has been assigned a USB address by the host and the firmware wants to enable USB connectivity.

```
UDADDR & _BV(ADDEN)
```

Comment: Is there something similar for VBUS detection to get the (not)plugged in?

Comment: @Majenko: `VBUS` in `USBSTA`.

Comment: Stupid question, but where do I go from here? Is it as easy as (UDADDR & _BV(ADDEN)) != B00000000 ?

Comment: `if (UDADDR & _BV(ADDEN)) ...`

Comment: Works but there is a problem with battery powered equipment when you disconnect the USB cable. This still returns true and after an restart it returns false. How to fix this?

Comment: Rewrite the firmware to deconfigure USB when disconnected.

Comment: This willl wait for serial monitor to be opened if usb connected before proceeding: 
if (UDADDR & _BV(ADDEN)){ while (!Serial);}